# Enable kwebkitpart in Konqueror

Tags: arch-linux, kde, settings, konqueror

In [KDE SC 4.5.0](http://www.kde.org/announcements/4.5/platform.php) it's possible to use a WebKit part for rendering in Konqueror. I don't think it's on by default (I could be wrong) and I believe I've installed all the requirements for it... How do I enable it?

I figured out how to switch it...

```
View -> View mode -> webkit
```

But you must be on a web page first. Problem is that this setting doesn't stick. I can't find a permanent setting. Does one exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found an [article](http://digitizor.com/2010/08/11/how-to-switch-to-webkit-in-konqueror-browser-kde-sc-4-5kubuntu/) posting how to do it for kubuntu.

The short of it is configure the file association for text/html (embedding) and set the first as webkit. I'm sure you should do it for application+xml/xhtml too. Maybe some others.